# Подскажите, как в Yii2 можно отключить вывод ошибок deprecated

Tags: php, yii2

Проблема в том, что я использую библиотеку, в которой содержатся устаревшие функции. Мне нужно, чтоб обычные ошибки и предупреждения выводились, а `deprecated` нет. Подскажите, кто с этим сталкивался.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);`  на `php`

Comment: @dima-opr: А в какой версии PHP вы столкнулись с `deprecated`? Дело в том, что логика yii2 написана с поддержкой PHP 5.4+. Даже в PHP 7.0 проблем не наблюдалось.

Comment: @romeo у автора ошибки в библиотеке, а не в самом ядре

Comment: Я использую библиотеку, которая к Yii2 никакого отношения не имеет. Просто в этой библиотеке содержатся функция с магическими кавычками и Yii2 мне отображает ошибку Deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

Не помню точно если в Yii2 механизм, можно просто в `index.php` (или где у вас инициализируются приложение) добавить такую строчку:

Если PHP >= 5.3.*

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);
```

Если PHP <= 5.2.*

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
```

И конечно советую почитать [документацию](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).

### UPD

Т.к. для `Yii2` действительно нужен `php >= 5.4.*`, то конкретно касаемо `Yii2` вариант для `php <= 5.2.*` отпадает (спасибо @romeo за комментарий)

Comment: yii2 поддерживает PHP 5.4+. Проблем с `deprecated` быть не должно. Разве что, ТС сам использует логику от 5.3 и ниже, но это за гранью здравого смыла, либо путает версию yii.

Comment: Я использую PHP 5.5. Но в том то и дело, что в этой версии, функция из библиотеки является устаревшей. Я использую библиотеку, написанную под PHP 5.3. Просто пытаюсь прикрутить её к Yii